# How to get a information or an nfc id of Android program programmatically?

Tags: android, nfc

I've tried some code from Stack Overflow but the result is only get nfc id from the card, I want to get a nfc id of my Android.

Comment: Have you tried with this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc

Comment: i already read that, but i have no idea to use which one @SanjayBhalani

Comment: Go with above-provided URL & follow the step @Eric

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val mTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

val id = byteArrayToHexString(mTag.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

First of all you should initialise an `NfcAdapter` when appropriate for you with this line

```
mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
```

Then override `onNewIntent` like this

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

    Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent: "+intent.getAction());

    if(tag != null) {
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        readFromNFC(ndef);
    }else{
        toastUser(getApplicationContext(), "Problem reading NFC tag!\nPlease try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

Finally read the NFC tag

```
private void readFromNFC(Ndef ndef) {
    try {
        ndef.connect();
        NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getNdefMessage();
        if(ndefMessage != null) {
            NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();

            //records will produce an array of strings stored on the tag
            //iterate through them as handle as required.

        }
        ndef.close();

    } catch (IOException | FormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```